# How to export an excel/pdf from Console App(.Net Core)

Tags: excel, pdf, .net-core

I tried to create a Console App from .Net Core. Wish able to doing some SQL Query and calculation then gnerate some summmary report and export as excel/pdf format.

I have tried  the Console App able to select some sql query from SQL server database already. However not sure how to save the results and export as excel/pdf format inside the Console App at .Net Core

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace SQLconnectionApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var SqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=myserver;Database=myDatabase;User Id=username;Password =password"))
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("Select * from table", SqlConnection))
                {

                    SqlConnection.Open();

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                          Console.WriteLine($"id: {reader["id"]}, Name: {reader["Name"]}");

                        }
                    }
                 #the job want to do 
                 #collect the result from SQL server
                 #output some reports file in the folder
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at Excel interop? Google it

Comment: @Skin - I have google the Excel Interop , are you meaning the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel? It seems only support the .NetFramework , does it able to support .Net Core, if I am wrong please let me know , many thanks.

Comment: no, you’re right, only .NetFramework. I glanced over that when reading your question.

Comment: EPPlus is thrown around as another option. Could that help?

Comment: Try this: https://www.grapecity.com/documents-api-excel it supports .NET Standard 2.0+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### install

```
dotnet add package Magicodes.IE.Pdf
```

### Code

Create Dto

```
    public class Student
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }
```

export to file

```
  public async Task ExportPdf()
        {
            var exporter = new PdfExporter();
            var result = await exporter.ExportListByTemplate("test.pdf", new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student
                {
                    Name = "MR.A",
                    Age = 18
                },
                new Student
                {
                    Name = "MR.B",
                    Age = 19
                },
                new Student
                {
                    Name = "MR.B",
                    Age = 20
                }
            });
        }
```

more https://github.com/dotnetcore/Magicodes.IE

Answer (score 1):

You can download this nuget package DocumentFormat.OpenXml which supports .net core